# ASP.NET MVC Form Submitting Twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have a simple form with a few questions. I am validating if the inputs are filled before the form is submitted using this (  https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/1000hz-bootstrap-validator/0.11.9/validator.min.js) library.

My form is like:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveAnswer", "Home", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", id = "answer", role = "form" }))
{             //.... Q1, Q2 ...etc

              <!-- Button (Double) -->
            <div class="form-group form-submit-button">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="button1id">Please save your response.</label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                <button type='submit' id="Save" name="SaveButton" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
 }
```

Form works, validation (if the input is filled) works.

Except that the database has 2 entries!!

This means 2 requests are coming upon form submission. I don't really submit 2 times.

The backend controller is:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]  
    public ActionResult SaveAnswer(FormCollection form)
    {
        var AnswerToAdd = new Answer();

        // Deserialize (Include white list!)
        TryUpdateModel(AnswerToAdd, new string[] { "Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5", "Q6", "Q7", "id"}, form.ToValueProvider());

        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

        AnswerToAdd.LastModifiedTime = now;

        db.Answers.Add(AnswerToAdd);

        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index"); 


    }
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. Post the backend code also. That may be causing some trouble

Comment: You might have multiple references to `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` in your page. Can you please make sure that you don't have included this js multiple times?

Comment: @It'satrap thx, I have posted the controller code.

Comment: @Arul no, the form's page has just 1 link for each library i.e. one for jquery one for validator library... I don't have jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js library included on my page.

Comment: your backend code also looks fine. To be sure, just look into the network tab of your browser and see how many http requests are made when you click the submit button. Also make sure to run the project in debug mode and place breakpoint on the `SaveAnswer` and see if it gets hit twice when you click the submit button. This will help you narrow down whether the problem is client side or server side.

Comment: @It'satrap yes, I checked in debug mode -- inside the Save Answer controller every code line takes two steps to progress (i..e I hit F10 twice for each line)...as of requests in network...I have to see

Comment: @davidnadal have you check in 'requests in network'?

Comment: @programtreasures the post method was called only once, as in the network tool on firefox.

Comment: @davidnadal so it is confirm that the form is submitted only once

Comment: @programtreasures yes, that is what is making this so frustrating...there are no duplicate libraries included too...3 days now stuck at this...tried a few different things at backend too..nothing is avoiding the double submission...

Comment: @davidnadal I understand your frustration, you can check by removing things one by one and check, i.e. remove your extra html, remove not require js css and you will get to a point, else you can post here your entire view so we can help you.

Comment: What exactly is `TryUpdateModel` doing? If it's trying to persist the entity model, then adding the model later in this action is going to create a new, duplicate record. You're probably after the Attach method, instead.

Comment: @TiesonT. Thanks, what should I change? replace it with attach method as in...

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592676(v=vs.113).aspx

Answer (score 0):

encountered this issue a week ago and tried everything i can do, but the last fix was that the chrome was causing this issue, when switched back to microsoft edge there was no double posting on the server/database.

if you found any other cause on this issue please let us know.